# Why did event.key stop working all of a sudden?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used `event.key` all day and now all of a sudden it gives me `undefined`. I'm 100% sure that earlier today it gave me the pressed key. Any ideas what could have happened or is something wrong with the code?

`$records_inputs` is a collection of inputs!

```
$records_inputs.on("input", function(e) {

    var pattern_only_digits = /[0-9]/;
    var input_value = $(this).val();

    alert(e.which + " " + e.key + " " + e.keyCode);

    if (e.keyCode != 8 && !pattern_only_digits.test(e.key)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    console.log(e);

    //$(this).val(numberFormatFromString(removeDotsFromString(input_value)));

});
```

Comment: use keypress events

Comment: @PranavCBalan works!! why? can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

The [`which`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) property only available for [keyboard events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) such as `keydown`, `keypress`, or `keyup` events. So use those events as per your need to get the pressed key.

```
$records_inputs.on("keypress", function(e) {
```

**FYI :** It's also suggested to use [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) property instead of [`which`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) property since [`which`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) is deprecated.

Available properties of [InputEvent are listed here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent#Properties).